# IBM MQ issue with getting message only on heartbeat interval

Tags: .net-core, ibm-mq, esb, heartbeat

I have a .net core Worker process using the latest library IBMMQDotnetClient 9.2.4. I am running into a test when there is a about 10k+ messages in queue. the application processes about 5.5k and then it processes random number of messages(mostly one message every heartbeat interval but have seen 100+) for every heartbeat interval time(currently have default value of 5). Has anyone ran into the issue. it would be great if someone knows the cause.

Update: There is no issue when putting message in the Queue it is only when getting  from the queue.

Comment: Maybe the same problem as described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70701927/638413)?

Comment: Is this XMS or just the normal .net API?

Comment: @DanielSteinmann it does not throw any error it is waiting for the message to come even though the messages are in the queue.

Comment: @JoshMc it is not XMS.

Comment: Are the messages larger than 15k ?

Comment: the max size for the messages so far is 11kb .

Comment: I would suggest trying at 9.2.0.4 and later when it comes out 9.2.5.  If you have a IBM suport contract then open a case with them.